# df_max['Data_Value'] = df_max['Data_Value']/10 getting error for this line

Tags: python, pandas

df_max['Data_Value'] = df_max['Data_Value']/10
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: What is code before `df_max['Data_Value'] = df_max['Data_Value']/10` ?

Comment: df3_max = df3[df3['Data_Value'] > df3['Month'].map(df_max['Data_Value'])]
df4_min = df3[df3['Data_Value'] < df3['Month'].map(df_min['Data_Value'])]
plt.scatter(df3_max.Month.tolist(),df3_max['Data_Value'],s=10,c='red') #values over max
plt.scatter(df4_min.Month.tolist(),df4_min['Data_Value'],s=10,c='black') #values under min
plt.xticks(list(df_max.index),['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'])

Comment: So add copy like `df3_max = df3[df3['Data_Value'] > df3['Month'].map(df_max['Data_Value'])].copy()` and `df4_min = df3[df3['Data_Value'] < df3['Month'].map(df_min['Data_Value'])].copy()`